# How to separate same data from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have option for select and it returns array of data, all of returned data have name of selected option in them. I need to take out this name from all and print it only once

## Logic

[image: one]

1. I select `Project 1`
2. It returns 4 results (in this sample)
3. All this 4 are included `project: Project 1`
4. I want to get `Project 1` only once in order to show it in my table
   header.

[image: two]

## Code

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'{{url('dashboard/getProjectVisits')}}/'+projectID,
    success:function(data){
        $('.addVisit').hide();
        //return existed data to schedules
        $('#schedule_table2').html('');
        $(data).each(function(_, i){
            var row = `<tr data-id="${i.id}">'+
            '<td>${i.fromDate}</td>'+
            '<td>${i.toDate}</td>'+
            '<td width="150">${i.location}</td>'+
            '<td>${i.description}</td>'+
            '<td width="100">${i.status}</td></tr>'`;
            $('#schedule_table2').append(row);
        });

        //rest of the code
    }
});
```

> I want to append that `Project 1` in my table header but I need to get
> it out of my loop first. Any idea how to?

Comment: you can use `data[0].project` as in your table header, and NOT include `project` in table column

Comment: @Azad damn that was easy! :)) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get distinct project values:

```
let arr = [{project:'project1'},{project:'project1'},{project:'project2'}];

const distinctPrj = arr.reduce((res,cur)=>{
  if (!res.includes(cur.project)) res.push(cur.project);
  return res;
},[])

console.log(distinctPrj);
```